# Drawing Text with MFC CDC

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, cdc

I cannot set text alignment correctly. For instance, if I do this, then bottom alignment gets lost

```
memDC.SetTextAlign(TA_BOTTOM); 
memDC.SetTextAlign(TA_RIGHT);
memDC.TextOutW(textRect.left, textRect.top, _T("HELLo"));
```

And if I do this, then right alignment gets lost.

```
memDC.SetTextAlign(TA_RIGHT);
memDC.SetTextAlign(TA_BOTTOM); 
memDC.TextOutW(textRect.left, textRect.top, _T("HELLo"));
```

There does not seem to exist a way to keep both alignments. Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're bitflags:

```
memDC.SetTextAlign(TA_RIGHT | TA_BOTTOM);
```